# How do I show the two following groups are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

If $G = \{ a \in \mathbb{R} | -1 < a < 1\}$ and $\star$ is a binary operation on $G$ defined as $$a \star b = \frac{a + b}{1 + ab},$$ then $(G, \star)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$

I am having a hard time deciding how should I define a function $f$ that I can then show is a homomorphism.

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle th(x+y)=\frac{th(x)+th(y)}{1+th(x)th(y)}$.

Answer (score 2):

One function which serves is [hyperbolic tangent $\tanh$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) and its inverse to map between $(-1,1)$ and $\Bbb R$. To go from $\Bbb R$ to $(-1,1)$ use $\tanh$. Note that $$\tanh(a+b)={\tanh a+\tanh b \over 1+\tanh a\tanh b}.$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, @Suzu

Comment: I still can't see how $f(x) = \tanh(x)$ defines a homomorphism. If $a, b \in G$, then $\tanh(a \star b) = \tanh(\frac{a + b}{1 + ab}) = \tanh (a) + \tanh(b)$ how?

Comment: @bakhtiar You already have the definition of $\star$, we are not looking for that. You can map $\Bbb R$ into $(-1,1)$ using $\tanh$ and you can map $(-1,1)$ into $\Bbb R$ using arctanh. The relation $\star$ is as defined in the question.